# Bringing the Header to the front so that the links work

Tags: html

I've just added a feature to my site which I followed from the [FortySeven Media](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/) website. It basically makes your Footer stick to the bottom of the browser.

However, now my Header is behind everything else and the links inside the Header are no longer clickable. Does anyone know how I can bring my Header back to the front.

Here's the page I'm working on right now, [404 - Skiroid](http://www.skiroid.com/error/404/). I'm trying to get that page to work before I fix all the other pages.

I've spent an hour messing around with it trying to get the Header back to the front. Everything I've tried doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For z-index to work you need to give the element a position of fixed,absolute or relative.

Your header has none of these but you declare a z-index.  Give your header `positon:relative` and it should work;